# React list component won't rerender after deleting one component from it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, web

I am writing a kind of a ToDo app in React, which has Boards, Lists and Cards as components. I am using an API to do operations with these components. Board has a list of List components, List component has a list of Card components.

The Board filters the list of List components to only display the ones set as open.
When I try to close a List from the Board, somehow the Board gets rerendered to only remove the last List component. I have checked it through Postman and the correct List gets closed, but I just can't get it to render properly. After refreshing the page, the Board component is rendered correctly, at the List components are displayed as expected.

Here is my code sample below.

```
//List component
 const archiveList = () => {
    fetch(
      `https://URL/${
        props.list.id
      }/closed?key=${API_KEY}&token=${TOKEN}&value=${true}`,
      {
        method: "PUT",
      }
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(props.setLists(props.lists.filter((list) => list.id !== props.list.id)))
  };

//Board component

const [lists, setLists] = useState([]);
const { selectedBoard } = useContext(BoardContext);


useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `https://URL/${getBoardId()}/lists?key=${API_KEY}&token=${TOKEN}`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setLists(data.filter((d) => d.closed === false)));
  }, [selectedBoard]);

const displayLists = () => {
    return lists.map((list, i) => {
      return (
        <Cell key={i} col={12} shadow={1}>
          {list.idBoard === getBoardId() ? ( <div>
            <List list={list} setLists={setLists} lists={lists} />
           </div>
          ) : (
            <div></div>
          )}
        </Cell>
      );
    });
  };
```

I am still new to React so this confuses me quite a bit. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: try to use `idBoard` instead of `i` for the `key=` something like this `<Cell key={list.idBoard} col={12} shadow={1}>`

Comment: @antoineso that does not help, every Cell needs to have a unique key when iterating through map, so I get an error when trying that. I don't think it has any influence my problem.

Comment: ok  I tought that passing index to key in react can cause this issue [see tihs article](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

Comment: Using `list.id` solved my problem actually. Thank you @antoineso! I was not aware the key could cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue in your List component at the last callback after fetching and converting data to json.

```
const archiveList = () => {
fetch(
  `https://URL/${
    props.list.id
  }/closed?key=${API_KEY}&token=${TOKEN}&value=${true}`,
  {
    method: "PUT",
  }
)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  // **** Please check the line below ****
  .then(props.setLists(props.lists.filter((list) => list.id !== props.list.id)))
  // **** It should have been like this **** 
  // .then(data => doSomethingWith(data))
};
 // Use the data from fetch in the next callback
```

Comment: unfortunatelly, that does not work for me, since I get the setLists method from props of the List component. So writing it like you are suggesting throws an error that the `setLists` in undefined.

Comment: you're supposed to pass the response from fetch to the next callback. You're converting the response to json but not utilizing it in the next callback function.

Comment: can you explain more about what exactly is getting returned from fetch call and how you want to utilize it?

Comment: only the status gets returned, so that data is useless for the following steps. As I have said in the comment on the question, the problem was solved after I changed `key={i}` to `key={list.id}`.